AUTO_INCREMENT value is incremented by one after a restart of MariaDB
I need your help to understand some behaviour of MariaDB/InnoDB.
I have a dump file I use to initialize my database.
Below is the dump file:
-- MariaDB dump 10.19  Distrib 10.11.5-MariaDB, for Win64 (AMD64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: capture_plan016
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   10.11.5-MariaDB

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `_secrol`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `_secrol`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `_secrol` (
  `SECROL_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SECROL_DESC` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`SECROL_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_swedish_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `_secrol`
--

LOCK TABLES `_secrol` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `_secrol` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `_secrol` VALUES
(1,'Role 1'),
(2,'Role 2');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `_secrol` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

As you can see the CREATE TABLE statement specify the AUTO_INCREMENT VALUE.
After playing this dump file, I check the AUTO_INCREMENT value and it is, as expected, equal to 3.
The strange behaviour (to me) occurs when i restart the MariaDB server (with a normal shutdown). After the restart the AUTO_INCREMENT value is 4.
But no INSERT nor DELETE were performed.
Well after some manipulations I managed to find a solution to this "problem" (I know it should not be a problem but I want to rely on predictable values only for test purposes).
If I use two seperates file (one for the table creation, and one for the inserts) it works fine with a predictible auto increment value.
But I would like to understand why the auto_increment value is changed when all the statements takes place in one file.
If somebody have some explanation he is welcome =D

The only guarantee for AUTO_INCREMENT is that the values will be distinct.
In your example, either "3" or "4" is valid; live with it.
There are numerous cases where ids are "burned" -- any sort of INSERT that fails to actually insert a row (due to ROLLBACK, certain crashes, duplicate key, etc.) will "burn" an id.  This is because the default (and fast) operation of AUTO_INCREMENT is to get the id(s) needed before seeing if the rows will actually be inserted.

Yes, you're right, for real cases I should not (and I do not) rely on AUTO_INCREMENT to be a specific value.
But to ease some testings I will. And as I replied to @RolandoMySQLDBA, using two seperates files did the trick. So it is not perfect, but I know it and will support the consequences :p.
Thank you nonetheless for your answer =)

@FlorianMasy - MariaDB has two ways to generate sequence numbers without using AUTO_INCREMENT. See if either works for you.

This may be a problem with how MariaDB stores auto_increment values
MariaDB has a setting innodb_auto_inc_lock_mode which governs it
In your case, the mysqldump being reloaded did what ? It locks the whole table, performs a bulk INSERT (more than one row being inserted is a bulk insert).
Please note what the MariaDB Documentation says on how auto_increment is handled

The AUTO_INCREMENT value for an InnoDB table can be set for a table by executing the ALTER TABLE statement and specifying the AUTO_INCREMENT table option. For example:
ALTER TABLE tab AUTO_INCREMENT=100;

However, in MariaDB 10.2.3 and before, InnoDB stores the table's AUTO_INCREMENT counter in memory. In these versions, when the server restarts, the counter is re-initialized to the highest value found in the table. This means that the above operation can be undone if the server is restarted before any rows are written to the table.
In MariaDB 10.2.4 and later, the AUTO_INCREMENT counter is persistent, so this restriction is no longer present. Persistent, however, does not mean transactional. Gaps may still occur in some cases, such as if a INSERT IGNORE statement fails, or if a user executes ROLLBACK or ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT.
For example:
CREATE TABLE t1 (pk INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, i INT, UNIQUE (i)) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO t1 (i) VALUES (1),(2),(3);
INSERT IGNORE INTO t1 (pk, i) VALUES (100,1);
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.099 sec)

SELECT * FROM t1;
+----+------+
| pk | i    |
+----+------+
|  1 |    1 |
|  2 |    2 |
|  3 |    3 |
+----+------+

SHOW CREATE TABLE t1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: t1
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `pk` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `i` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pk`),
  UNIQUE KEY `i` (`i`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

If the server is restarted at this point, then the AUTO_INCREMENT counter will revert to 101, which is the persistent value set as part of the failed INSERT IGNORE.
# Restart server
SHOW CREATE TABLE t1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: t1
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `pk` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `i` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pk`),
  UNIQUE KEY `i` (`i`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=101 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


Please note how this example from the MariaDB Documentation presents a problem which includes restarting MariaDB and how auto_increment can still be affected.
Check your version of MariaDB. You either have an older version of MariaDB or you are still encountering a gap lock problem regardless of the version of MariaDB.
CAPTAIN'S LOG SUPPLEMENTAL
Try this just to see if FLUSH TABLES has an affect on the auto_increment:

Reload the mysqldump
Run FLUSH TABLES;
Restart MariaDB


Thank you for the insights. I'm using MariaDB 10.11.5 so the AUTO_INCREMENT counter should be persistent.
The way I found to get around this, was to use two separates dump files.
The first dump file is produced with the flags --routines --no-data.
The second dump file is produced with the flags --no-create-info --skip-triggers
Playing this two dump file in this order cause the AUTO_INCREMENT value to not change even if I restart MariaDB. So it does the job for me.
I'll give a try to the FLUSH TABLES anyway.
